# How to load new jar files dynamically to JavaVM

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a already created JavaVM C object which is given by my library, But I need to add more jar and java files to that in my application.

What can I do?

The library uses the JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&p_JNIEnv, &args); function for creating the JavaVM first time. My application needs to add more options.

Someone please let me know are there any function to load java objects dynamically to already created JavaVM object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question...

```
Is there any function to dynamically add java objects to a running JVM?
```

Then use the following to dynamically add JARs to you application. (Add error checking and exception handling as necessary)

```
public synchronized void addJarToClassPath(final File jarFile) {
    final String methodName = "addURL";
    final Class<?>[] methodTypes = new Class[] { URL.class };
    try {
        final Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, methodTypes);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[] { jarFile.toURI().toURL() });
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load " + jarFile.getAbsolutePath(), e);
    }
}
```